# Is there any standard parameter to use L2 as a limiter?

Tags: sound, nuendo

If I keep the threshold meter near -3dB and the outceiling near 0.5 dB,will that be okay to make a perfect Nuendo project?

Comment: It depends entirely on what your programme content is doing. There is no "one setting", you need to listen to it.

Comment: Yeah; and what is a "perfect Nuendo project"? It means nothing, really. You need to be as specific as possible. With things you have tried, why they didn't work, what is your goal etc... Other than that, the presets are probably good *starting points*.

Comment: Simmilar to your last question http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/39748/why-is-the-project-getting-hard-after-using-l2 Not sure if it is a duplicate. The last sentence is similar to this question.

Comment: This seems like you are asking the exact same thing as your previous post.  As this is a better phrasing of the question, I have closed the last one as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no standard setting to use to make something sound good.  Compression is used to reduce the dynamic range of your sound and makes it have less difference between the softest and loudest parts by reducing the rate at which the signal gets "louder" (the ratio) beyond a given amount of signal (threshold).

The proper way to compress (or if you should compress at all) is dependent on the type of sound you have and what your desired end goal is.  There is no "right" answer.  It depends entirely on what you are trying to accomplish.